# IE 7 transparent PNG problem

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, png

I have this site (http://techlipse.net/test/agb) with a css layout. The PNGs with transparent backgrounds (they are saved as is from Fireworks as FW png) cycle with fade effect while theres another div behind it with clouds moving (telerik rad rotator) .. Transparent images create this black outline around them. If anyone explains me what happens here I will deeply appreciate it. Thx in advance

Comment: it also does this in IE8... interesting!

Comment: I know there are still issues with PNG in IE (7/8) with fading in/out leaving pixels, but this one is new to me.

Comment: haha jus downloaded ie8 update and ie do not launc at all :)
felt this would happen tough

Comment: interesting... the images load fine by themselves, its only when stacked on the other bits that the bug shows up.

Comment: yeah right? .. its when the cycle jQuery plug in comes into play

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, if you put the image in a container and fade the container instead of the image itself the problem won't present itself.  Haven't tried this myself.

- [This post talks about](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/04/26/412263.aspx) some of the limitations of the PNG implementation in IE7
- [Here's an interesting discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/1f693c5f4e8ea650/f3bc9685ccb40e70) about the problem where poster 'eric' mentions (way down in the discussion) the solution I wrote above

Comment: i tried it .. wrapped the Repeater (asp.net comp) with a div tag .. did not work .. then eve gave the div an id and even a css class :)